# Не оправляются письма при регистрации пользователя в Wordpress

Tags: email, wordpress

При регистрации пользователя на сайте под управлением Wordpress  не отправляются письма пользователям. Другие письма отправляются, документ class-phpmailer.php настроен соответствуюшим образом. Даже на всякий случай настроен плагин     WP-Mail-SMTP. При попытке восстановить пароль пишет "Сообщение не удалось отправить. Возможная причина: на сервере отключена функция mail()."  Но грешить на хостера не могу, ибо другие письма отправляются. 
Да и хостер ru-center.
Кто-нибудь что-нибудь может подсказать?

Comment: Вы письма через настроенный SMTP хотите отправлять или все-таки стандартной функцией mail в php? Если первое - проверяйте настроки подключения. Если второе - отключите отправку почты через SMTP.

Comment: а как можно строить отправку писем (именно приветственых) через smtp в wordpress?